# css-loader changes id name in the result css file

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader, storybook

I am currently using **storybook** and I have problem with importing a CSS file for my custom component. I have a custom JS and CSS file that creates a custom HTML element and I import the JS file to my storybook.js file.

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

However, the problem is that when I inspect the component, one of my id selector change from

```
#my_id {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem 1rem;
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    height: 0.1rem;
}
```

into something like this

```
#_2mi2YFOpgJGU5rtfy7l3RI {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem 1rem;
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    height: 0.1rem;
}
```

Is there something that I need to do? I think the problem lies with the css loader

Comment: I do not use css-loader, but are you sure that this is not the standard behavior of css-loader?

Comment: this is because you enabled `modules`, check this [reference](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope)

Answer (score 0):

You try change the options to this:

```
options: {
  modules: true,
  importLoaders: 1,
  localIdentName: '[hash:base64:5]'
}
```